# How to install Ubuntu OS on USB, without booting & Ubuntu OS running inside Win XP 32 bit & Win 7 home premium 64 bit?

Tags: usb

Please help me install Ubuntu OS latest build on a Kingston Data Traveler USB 8 GB Stick FAT32, completely clean & formatted, now, WITHOUT BOOTING from USB, Ubuntu OS should load & run inside Win XP 32 Bit OS & Win 7 Home Premium 64 Bit OS, whenever, I insert my USB stick in any port, WITHOUT USING ANY VIRTUAL HOST like VMware or Virtualbox & SHOULD NOT INSTALL UBUNTU OS ON ANY MACHINE, just like Win 7 Professional OS & Win 7 Ultimate OS have Win XP Mode running inside them, for legacy software & is able to access, modify & save all file & folders of the host machine, should run in a different interface, but here I am using a USB Stick, please tell me if its possible ?

(http://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/sshot472.png)

Comment: xp mode is a virtual machine. Is this the type of setup you are talking about - http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/windows-xp-mode/

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to run Ubuntu inside of a Windows environment without a vm or emulation. If you want to be able to take the USB to another computer that doesn't have Virtualbox installed, then you might try to just install Virtualbox on the USB with Ubuntu.

Comment: **@Sepero, Thanx,** please tell me how do I achieve this, do I need to install Virtualbox on USB, then, I need to install Ubuntu OS on top of it, can you please tell me, how do I do this, for Chrome OS there is Hexxah (http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/), but, how do I do this for Ubuntu OS, can you please let me know the entire process Step by Step, consider, I do this on Win XP OS 32 bit Desktop, will there be a denial if I use this USB stick on a Win 7 Home Premium OS 64 bit, which latest Ubuntu OS build do I need install 64bit or 32bit, one more thing, after I install it successfully, so, will I

Comment: 1) Install Virtualbox 32bit on the USB drive. (If you need help with this, you need to create a question on superuser.com) 2) Start the Virtualbox from the USB drive. 3) Create a new virtual machine for Ubuntu, and save it's virtual harddrive to the USB. (again, if you need help- superuser.com)

Comment: **@Sepero** Thanx, already done, please check !!!!!